# Suggestions handling company merger - One uses Office365, the other GSuite

Tags: g-suite, office365

Couple of key points for now
- e.g. companyA = Office365, companyB = GSuite
- Both companies on separate domains and no immediate need to migrate to one
- Ideally we for now we don't NEED to have them all using Office365 or all using GSuite HOWEVER, it would be good for companyA.com to occasionally log into company B's GSuite managed services and visa versa

So, I was wondering if it would work doing federated login between both systems so that companyA can log into a system using Google sign in via their own companyA.com email and a companyB user could log into an Office 365 system using their companyB.com email?

Is this doable or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your business needs.

Based on what you described, I think doing this might be enough for you:

1. Create [Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251)-licensed users for the Office 365 users in your G Suite domain. This would allow them to collaborate with the G Suite users on Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, etc.
2. Set up [Calendar Interop](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2798684) between G Suite and Exchange Online. This would allow users from both sides to invite each other to events while seeing availability, etc.

If I'm wrong, and you need more, you can look up Google Cloud Directory Sync (GCDS) for syncing users/groups/etc. from Active Directory to G Suite and/or [user provisioning](https://support.google.com/a/topic/6400789), and maybe even [migration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9413033) (but that's a much more complex operation).

Federated login as also possible, but again, it really depends on the setup you need (for example, maybe you want to use Office365/Azure AD as the identity provider, and G Suite as the service provider, or maybe the other way around).